# Retrieve userdata from launch template

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a launch template in my account which is being used by an autoscaling group.

Is there any way I can retrieve the userdata which is baked inside the template from either the console or the aws cli?

I could always login an instance and find it there but I'm wondering if this functionality is exposed somehow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I ended up using:

```
aws ec2 describe-launch-template-versions --launch-template-id lt-123 --query 'LaunchTemplateVersions[0].LaunchTemplateData.UserData' --output text | base64 -d
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use AWS CLI's [describe-launch-template-versions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-launch-template-versions.html) which returns `UserData`.